# Help with an Ordinary First Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please consider the following differential equation:

\begin{eqnarray*}
2xy \frac{dy}{dx} + (1+x)y^2 &=& e^x
\end{eqnarray*}

I do not know how to solve this problem. I do not believe it is a separable differential equation. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=xy^2$
$$\frac{du}{dx}+u=e^x$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I can, thank you. Bob.

Answer (score 2):

Change of variables $u = y^2$ makes it linear.

Comment: Indeed, this substitution is obvious because it can be written as a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation).